# Merging Object to Array with matching IDs - Angular 2+ / Ionic 2+

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I have an array with objects. In each of these objects, there's another object within for itemID. For example

```
[
{object1: 123, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 1, type: red}
{object2: 124, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 2, type: blue}
{object3: 125, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 2, type: blue}
{object4: 127, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 1, type: red}
]
```

hasObjects is my inner object. I have other objects I'm retrieving from another endpoint and I would like to combine that data into this array based on that innerObjectID. Here's what the other objects look like -- each one is it's own api call

```
{ innerObjectID: 1, data: 1231231209381029381 } 
{ innerObjectID: 2, data: 13464531209381029381 }
```

I would like to combine that data into the array above. So I would look through that array and add the object based on ID.

What I want:

```
[
    {object1: 123, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 1, type: red, data: 1231231209381029381}
    {object2: 124, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 2, type: blue, data: 13464531209381029381}
    {object3: 125, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 2, type: blue, data: 13464531209381029381}
    {object4: 127, hasObjects: {innerObjectID: 1, type: red, data: 1231231209381029381}
    ]
```

Component.ts

```
setItems(){

    this.service.setItems().subscribe((res) => {
      this.items = res

      this.stops.map(res => {
        this.getIcons(res.hasObjects)

      })      
    })
  }

    getIcons(iconID){
      this.service.getIcons(iconID.imageID).subscribe(icon => {
            this.newIcons = icon

              icon.data = 'data:image/png;base64,' + icon.data;
              let newObj = Object.assign( iconID.imageID, this.newIcons.innerObjectID)
              console.log(newObj, 'new object')
      })
    }
```

What is happening above is I'm just getting the result and not able to add that object inside the correlated object.

Comment: Could you specify what likely are the corresponding object names within your code?

Answer (score 0):

The structure of your objects is a little confusing, but as a general rule, you can send a request for each object in your array. Then you can use `Promise.all` to execute code after all the requests are back and build a new array from there.

It could look similar to this

```js
const requests = []

objects.map(object => {
  // Assuming this.getOtherObject() returns an observable with an object 
  // with the following signature { innerObjectID: 1, data: 123 } 
  requests.push(this.getOtherObject(object.hasObjects.innerObjectID).toPromise())
})

Promise.all(requests).then(res => {
  const newItems = []

  // res is an array containing all the responses from the requests
  res.map(innerObject => {
    const object = objects.find(
      object => object.hasObjects.innerObjectID === innerObject.innerObjectID
    )

    newItems.push({
       ...object,
       hasObjects: { ...object.hasObjects, data: innerObject.data }
    })
  })

  this.items = newItems
})
```

I didn't test the code, but hopefully this gives you an idea of how to do it.

Comment: Array "push" returns the length of the array. At object.map function, don't you just map numbers to objects array?

Comment: I might not understand what part of the code you are talking about correctly, but `push` adds an element to the end of the array. We don't need its return value for anything.

Comment: in the second line of your code, requests.push function just returns the length of requests array. So the map function fills objects array just with numbers. I know push function pushes an item to array but the function itself returns the length of array.

Comment: Iterating through an array with `map` does not modify the array, so the `objects` array will still be filled with the original objects and won't be modified.

Answer (score 0):

It is not good idea to use promises in the map function, because map function needs somethings for mapping but when you send request to server you only have a promise. Nothing to give map function. Just traverse your array and send request for all your item. This code should work:

```
setItems(){    
    this.service
        .setItems()
        .subscribe((res) => {
           this.items = res;

           this.items.forEach((item, i, arr) => {
             this.getIcons(arr[i]);//here we pass by reference 
           });      
         });
}

 getIcons(item){
      this.service
          .getIcons(item.hasObjects.innerObjectID)//null check here
          .subscribe(icon => {
              item.hasObjects.data = icon.data;
      })
    }
```

Comment: if I do console.log(item) in the getIcons function I'm only getting the first object of the array unfortunatly